# Index changes from zero in python array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a long biopac file that I was able to import using bioread (python package). The array consist of more than 1 million integers.
I need to extract time point from the array. Basically, when the object is changed from zero (0) I should take the index of that point (the array's index is the time in milliseconds). Then, when its back to zero I should also take this time point. 
I have tried a nested if's without success. it looked like that:

```
for i,v enumerate(array):
    if v != 0:
        time.append(i/1000)
        continue
        if v==0:
            time_offset.append(i/1000)
```

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Please post your code with correct indentation. It's impossible to tell what you're doing from what you posted.

Comment: If you've really nested the second `if` inside the first one, it will never execute. The `continue` statement goes to the next iteration of the loop, skipping over the rest of the code in the loop.

Comment: Sorry for not indenting it correctly.

Comment: Don't just apologize, fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a state variable to keep track of whether you're looking for zero or non-zero.

```
time.append(0)
look_for_zero = array[0] != 0
for i, v in enumerate(v[1:]):
    if look_for_zero and v == 0:
        look_for_zero = False
        time.append(i/1000)
    elif not look_for_zero and v != 0:
        look_for_zero = True
        time.append(i/1000)
```

Comment: Seems like you have solved the issue!
Thank you for the answer.